# Detect device up-down movement using sensors

Tags: android

I am trying to detect if the user is moving the device in a diagonal motion (like a sword move). Even if it is vertical move then fine. I just need to know that he moved it from top to bottom. I am exploring sensors (mainly accelerator, gyroscope and linear accelerometer).

I can't seem to figure out how to do the detection. Any working example out there? or Pointer?
Thank you

Comment: The gyroscope is used to detect rotation, it won't help you.  I'd look at the accelerometer and look for sudden accelerations in the same direction (or close to) as the gravity vector.  Of course you'll also need to somehow avoid false positives with the upward motions causing deceleration-  if you can wait for the entire motion to be done you can look for acceleration in/close to gravity followed by the reverse within a certain time frame.

Comment: Thank you Gabe for the answer. I read it like 3 times trying to understand the details :) . I can wait for the whole motion to be done (does the phone have to come to complete stop? What if the use does it again?) I just need to detect once that he is bringing it down.  Do you happen to have a link to what you described?

Comment: If you don't wait for the phone to come to a stop, you run the risk of false positives on upwards movement.  Remember that accelerometers detect acceleration not movement-  a phone stopping when moving up looks just like a phone starting to move down.  You can only guess which is which by seeing if the motion is paired with an opposite acceleration at the end.  If you remember the original Wii games had a lot of problems with this-  moves were read in the opposite direction.

Comment: I see your point. Actually for my purpose this false positive might work in my favor. Basically  I want to detect when the user is moving the phone  in a sword motion (so whether it is up- down or down-up will yield the same action to me). The question remains: How can I detect that movement from accelormeter (or linear acceleramoter)? If you can put sample code/formula in the answer then I can try it and accept the answer

Comment: Have you ever found a solution for this? can you please share your knowledge if yes?

Comment: I actually gave up on this as it seemed to work sometimes and sometimes it does not depending on speed and how the phone is held. So we went with the shake gesture instead